# QgsVariableEditorWidget does not save changes

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, widget, qgis-variable

I would like to edit the variables of a composer item in QGIS 2.18.x.
The widget itself is working so far. In my example, I am selecting a *QgsComposerLabel* called "Plankopf" to show its variables.

What is not working so far is:

- *saving the edits*: I thought that changes done throught the *QgsVariableEditorWidget* would be saved but that's not the case.
  What do I have to change to get added/updated variables saved?
- *showing changed Variables in the Composer-Window*: Even if I change variables with `QgsExpressionContextUtils.setComposerItemVariable()`, the changes are not visible in the Composer window. How can I refresh the variables widget in the Composer window?

  ```
  # -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
  from qgis.core import QgsExpressionContextUtils, QgsExpressionContext
  from qgis.gui import QgsVariableEditorWidget
  from qgis.utils import iface
  from PyQt4.QtGui import QInputDialog, QWidget, QFormLayout, QPushButton, QLineEdit
  from PyQt4 import QtCore
  from PyQt4.QtCore import QPoint

  class inputdialogdemo(QWidget):
      def __init__(self, parent = None):
         super(inputdialogdemo, self).__init__(parent)

      def getItem(self):
         items = []
         composerId = 0
         composers = iface.activeComposers()
         for item in composers:
             items.append( item.composerWindow().windowTitle() )
         item, ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, u'Auswahl', 
           u'Druckzusammenstellung wählen', items, 0, False)
         if ok and item:
             return item

   ex = inputdialogdemo().getItem()
   print ex

   composerId = 0
   composers = iface.activeComposers()
   for item in composers:
       if item.composerWindow().windowTitle() == ex:
           break
       composerId += 1

  target_citem = NULL
  def itemsuche(name):
      for citems in composers[composerId].composition().items():
          if type(citems).__name__=='QgsComposerLabel':
              if citems.displayName() == name:
                  return citems
                  break


  target = itemsuche('Plankopf')

  canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
  variable_editor_widget = QgsVariableEditorWidget()
  expression_context = QgsExpressionContext()


  expression_context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.composerItemScope(target))

  variable_editor_widget.setContext(expression_context)

  variable_editor_widget.reloadContext()
  variable_editor_widget.setEditableScopeIndex(0)
  print(variable_editor_widget.context())
  print(variable_editor_widget.editableScope())
  print(variable_editor_widget.settingGroup())
  print(variable_editor_widget.variablesInActiveScope())

  mapcanvas_upperleft = canvas.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0))



  offset_x = 0
  offset_y = 30
  pos_x = mapcanvas_upperleft.x() + offset_x

  pos_y = mapcanvas_upperleft.y() + offset_y
  variable_editor_widget.setGeometry(pos_x, pos_y, canvas.width()/3, canvas.height()*0.75)


  variable_editor_widget.show()
  print variable_editor_widget.pos().x()
  print variable_editor_widget.pos().y()
  target.setHtmlState(0)
  target.setHtmlState(2)
  ```

Comment: You could try connecting the scopeChanged() signal to the reloadContext() slot